# jQuery getting closest html when I have to use the same IDs for forms

Tags: jquery, siblings, closest

Firstly I know I shouldn't have the same IDs, but in this case it unavoidable ... I am trying to click a button that will take the `.html()` of a `div` and add that text to an input field. Problem is that everything has the same IDs and there will be an unknown number of them.  Example is:

```
<div id="Product">
    <div id="Product-stats"><div class="builder-name">Example Builder</div></div>
    <form><input id="abc" value=-""></input></form>
    <a href="#" class="cart-get-quote-button"></a>
<div>

<div id="Product">
    <div id="Product-stats"><div class="builder-name">Another Builder</div></div>
    <form><input id="abc" value=-""></input></form>
    <a href="#" class="cart-get-quote-button"></a>
<div>

<div id="Product">
    <div id="Product-stats"><div class="builder-name">Third Builder</div></div>
    <form><input id="abc" value=-""></input></form>
    <a href="#" class="cart-get-quote-button"></a>
<div>
```

So I need to click each link and have the builder-name content copied to the relative input value, obviously I can get this to work with just one set, but not multiple, so I though maybe trying to use sibling? or closest? This is what I have that does not work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.cart-get-quote-button').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('input[id="abc"]').val($(this).closest('.builder-name').html());
    }); 
});
```

Comment: You do not `have to use` same IDs. Using an ID **more than once** results in **invalid html**. Use classes instead. It's is never unavoidable !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since multiple identical ids are illegal in HTML, they won't work, and you simply can't use them in your JS.  Whatever solution you try it has to ignore IDs entirely.

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/30ugpw62/) (I have fixed several other errors in your HTML).  This works:

```
var text = $(this).closest('div').find('.builder-name').text();
$(this).closest('div').find('input').val(text);
```

Note you have several other errors in your HTML, and no JS will work until you fix them.  They're probably just typos here on SO:

- hyphen in your input `... value=-"">`, should be `... value="">`;
- closing `Product` `</div>` is actually a new open `<div>`;
- You don't need `</input>`;

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to do anything? and thanks for the typo pickups

Comment: @JonJones Not sure what you mean ... did you check the JSFIddle?  It works, are you not seeing that?

Comment: @JonJones - I had left some logging in which was breaking, I've removed it and now it works, sorry.